# Nested map in Typescript and React return error this expression is not callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx

I'm using Typescript with React and I want to return some JSX from this function. I've never had trouble with nested map loop but for some reason I have an error now that I'm using Typescript. Is it bad practice to do a nested loop like so? It gives me a 'this expression is not callable' error.

Updates: The code runs, but the .map is highlighted in red and it doesn't allow me to build the project. See the image below.

```
const getSelect = () => {
    return <div>
        {
            options.map( (option, index) => {
                return <div>
                    <p>{option.name}</p>
                    {
                        option.values.map( (value) => {
                            return <p>{value}</p>
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            })
        }
    </div>
}

const options: Option[] = [
    {
        name: "categories",
        values: ["cameras", "rolls", "magazine"]
    },
    {
        name: "type",
        values: ["point-and-shoot", "slr", "for beginners"]
    },
    {
        name: "availability",
        values: ["available only"]
    }
]

export type Option = {
  name: string;
  values: string[] | number[];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code. Can you post the structure of `options`?

Comment: you don't check if option.values is array. Are sure that option.values exist and is array type ?

Comment: add checking option.values.langth > 0 && option.values.map(value => ...

Comment: @DeanJames, I posted the Option Structure

Comment: @Robert, option.values exist, see the Option structure

Comment: @UladzKha, I did and I can see the logs

Comment: this fix it : values: Array<string | number> . but i don't know why :)

Answer (score 1):

So I did more research and fixed the problem. I added the union type inside the nested map and now everything works fine.

```
(option.values as (string | number)[]).map( (value) => {
                                    return <p>{value}</p>
                                })
```

Comment: [...option.values].map().. works as well :) but i think declaring type by Array constructor is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
export type Option = {
  name: string;
  values: string[] | number[];
}
```